# Can't create new instances by using a list element as the name for the new variable

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, nameerror

I can't create new instances of the class `Pokemon` using list element `line[1]` as the name of the instance.

```
pokedex = open('../resource/lib/public/pokedex.csv', 'r')
first_line = pokedex.readline() #Skip the header

class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, number, name, type1, type2, HP, attack, defense, special_atk,special_def, speed, generation, legendary, mega):
        self.number = int(number)
        self.name = str(name)
        self.type1 = type1
        self.type2 = type2
        self.HP = int(HP)
        self.attack = int(attack)
        self.defense = int(defense)
        self.special_atk = int(special_atk)
        self.special_def = int(special_def)
        self.speed = int(speed)
        self.generation = int(generation)
        self.legendary = bool(legendary)
        self.mega = bool(mega)

for line in pokedex:
    line = line.strip().split(",") 
    #line[1] is the name (string) of the Pokemon instance
    line[1] = Pokemon(*line)

print(Kakuna) #NameError: name 'Kakuna' is not defined
print(line[1]) #This gives a correct instance created from the last line of the file
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the file contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error makes sense since you didn't ever define the name `Kakuna`. You're assigning the new instance to the second element of `line` with

```
line[1] = Pokemon(*line)
```

That's not what you wanted to do, I guess.

There are ways to do this dynamically, however I urge you not to do so: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Use a `dict` instead:

```
pokemons = {}
for line in pokedex:
    line = line.strip().split(",") 
    #line[1] is the name (string) of the Pokemon instance
    pokemons[line[1]] = Pokemon(*line)
```

You can then access the instances with

```
print(pokemons['Kakuna'])
```

Comment: And if you really need to, you can do `globals().update(pokemons)`/`locals().update(pokemons)` afterwards...